# Useless tag listed

Tags: discussion, tag-management

I looked through the tag list. In the tag list there is a ["ca"-tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ca). It has no description, no followers, no questions and very likely no meaning.

Shouldn´t it be removed from the list ?

If yes, who is able to delete it ?